# How To Preview Prestashop Invoice Without Printing It To a PDF File

Tags: html, prestashop-1.6

How you would do this?

I'm trying to stylized a Prestashop Invoice. And it's tedious to complete for me, since I don't have a chance to preview it without printing it first to a PDF.

Is there any way to preview it without having to print it? I'm thinking of a way just like when debugging html pages with Chrome Dev or Firefox Developer tools.

This is on Prestashop 1.6.0.14

Comment: Did you manage to Do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the invoice pdf from backoffice.
Orders->invoices->generate pdf by date.

Comment: how does this answer the question? :|